# Is it Possible to Create Mac Applications without using Interface Builder at all ..?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm using XCode and Interface Builder to Create a NSStatus Item Object. The IBActions and IBOutlets were in my AppDelegate class and i had no trouble of using them. After a while, i have moved the IBActions and IBOutlets into a Separate Class ,Created A NSObject in the MainMenu.nib file, pointed the NSObject class to new IBActions class file.

But then i experienced some issues, the Menu was not at all popping from the NSStatusItem. I knew it's my Mistake , i did something wrong with Interface Builder in binding Actions. It's really Complicated using Interface Builder for me.

SO i just created NSStatusItem,NSMenu,NSMenuItem using my code at all and then set the target and actions. It's working fine and it's really very easy just to code rather than using IB.

However i want to confirm that i can create Window apps for Mac without using Interface Builder. Is it Possible ..?

I accept i'm not good with IB (IB is great for Guys who understand it better, i come from CPP/Java BacKground, no clue what IB even is).

And is the MainMenu.nib file required , if i don't use IB and just Xcode only.

Comment: I hereby confirm that you can create UI purely programmatically and Apple will not send assassins after you for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create apps without Interface Builder, but you'll end up doing a lot more work than you would with the help of IB.

Here's a first part of article series that I read a while back about working without nibs:

http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/05/16/working-without-a-nib-part-1/